# Dual National: Visa in expired passport, have valid passport from other country

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality

Can one enter the UK with a valid UK entry visa on an expired passport of one nationality and a valid passport of another nationality? I would be grateful for any references or links.

Comment: I doubt it. You were granted a Visa as a citizen of country A applying the rules and criteria for that country. That means you need a valid country A passport to use the Visa. That you also have a passport of country B is mostly irrelevant. A visa in an expired passport is typically fine as long as you can show an up-to-date passport of the same country as well. I suggest renewing your expired passport. Usual disclaimer: immigration laws are horribly complicated and it depends a lot on your specific details

Comment: Thank you. I needed that clarification.

Answer (score 3):

No.
You have to use the passport that is linked to your immigration status. Both passports (the valid and the expired one with the visa) must be from the same country. The combination of your other passport and your valid visa will not prove that you have entry clearance.

Source: [Travel to and from the UK](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa)

> You can use the valid visa in your expired passport when you’re travelling to and from the UK. You’ll need to travel with your expired and your new passport.

AFAIK this is common to all countries that allow entry using valid visa in expired passport with new passport eg USA.

Comment: Thank you. I had a hunch that that was the case.